# MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS problem even though all the connections are closed properly

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jsp

I not very good in java.
I have made a website for a client but am continuously getting an error like **Server connection failure during transaction. Due to underlying exception: 'com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: User root already has more than 'max_user_connections' active connections'.**
The website hosting that I am using provides only 10 max_user_connections. But if I continuously use that site, I get this error because of continuously hits on the webserver.

What can be the reason behind this?
Am I not closing the connections right?
I have closed all the connections using `con.close()`.

Please help

Regards Apurv

To open the connection I have used

```
Connection con=null;
Statement st=null;
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
String useq="root";
String paq="manager";
String url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jayna?autoReconnect=true";
con=DriverManager.getConnection(url,useq,paq);
st=con.createStatement();
```

To close the connection I have used

```
if(rs!=null){
rs.close();
}
if(st!=null){
st.close();
}
if(con!=null){
con.close();
}
```

I haven't used a database pool but what can be the use of that when I am closing each of the connection properly??

Comment: What server are you using? Do you use some connection pooling mechanism?  Do you have some code to show us?

Comment: Well if the server says you're exceeding the number of allocated connections it is probably right, so there must be something in your code that causes connections to remain open, or maybe 10 connections just isn't enough for your app, especially if no connection pooling was used.  without seeing any code it's hard, even impossible, to determine what's going on.

Comment: Luckily I'm not your client. :p

Comment: Hi Apurv, do u use finally block for the close connection code?

Comment: Elite its my first time..Please dont mock at me.:p.  Cyril yes i have used it in a finally block..What can be the other reasons??

Comment: @Apurv are you certain that all exceptions that may occur are dealt with in the right way?  The sequence of if ... close() suggests otherwise.  Plus you still have to consider that 10 connections may just not be enough for your application.  And, consider using connection pooling.

Comment: Giving some links that can make me clear of what you are saying would be very helpful..:)

Comment: @Apurv some links pointing to Tomcat's connection pooling added as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a case of connection leak.

1. Are you sure, you have closed all the connections?
2. Conneciton.close() throws IOException. Check if it is successfully able to close connections.
3. Use netstat or other tools to find whether connections are really closed or are in WAITING state or something.

Comment: I have checked in mysql using "SHOW PROCESSLIST" but still it is not closing. There are many connections in the waiting state..

Comment: It's ok. You close connection with db from your client but not on db server. In processlist you see connection/threads which are ready to get new queries.

Comment: But my problem isnt solved. Can you give me a link of how to properly close all the connections in jsp. I need some sheer advice on doing this because whole of my website is completed and this error has eaten me up from inside..:(

Answer (score 0):

I think you should increase number of connections. Because if there are 10 slow query and you get 11 requests to your site 11 request couldn't be processed and you get this error.
So:

1. Try increase a number of connections.
2. Try to find slow queries(using slow query log) and optimize them

Comment: Its from the website hosting side. EATJ.com has just provided 10 max no. of connections and when i try to increase the connections it has a privilige problem..:(

Comment: You should profile your queries. I believe that this error doesn't connect to java close problem.

Comment: Could you get info from your hosting about slow queries in your site? It makes by enabling slow_query_log in my.cnf file.

Comment: If not you should get each query and run EXPLAIN query. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/explain.html

Answer (score 0):

Connection pooling is a technique to provide a set of ready-to-use connections, one of the advantages being that you save the creation/opening time on each call.  Another advantage is that the connection pooler can help detect abandoned connections, ie connections that the application forgot to close.

There's a standard connection pool in Tomcat, for 5.x version Tomcats look [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html) for some info, for version 6 look [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html) and for version 7 info can be found [here](http://people.apache.org/~fhanik/jdbc-pool/jdbc-pool.html).  Its `removeAbandoned` and `logabandoned` features can help you determine whether your app really forgets to close connections, or 10 just isn't enough - see Andrej's suggestion, you should profile your queries.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, you either are not getting connections closed or your application simply needs more than 10 concurrent connections under some load conditions.

1. If the error always occurs on the 11th request, it's likely you're never getting the connections closed.
2. If it occurs sometime later, unpredictably, **and goes away on its own**, it's more likely 10 simply isn't sufficient for certain load scenarios.
3. If it occurs later, unpredictably, but never goes away on its own, it's possible you're failing to close connections only in specific cases that aren't hit every time.

If 10 is too small for some load scenarios (option 2), you should both check your queries and code logic to ensure you're not holding connections way longer than necessary **and** you should probably try to move to a Connection Pool, as others have suggested. Among other things, creating new Connections from scratch has more overhead than reusing them from a pool, so that could be causing individual accesses to take much longer than necessary.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be solved by using a Singleton class structure for initializing connection objects.
Using the Singleton pattern, whenever a connection object is initialized, rather than creating a new object, it will look for existing instance of connection object and use that one, if it exists.